# Using Redcarpet Gem with .erb file

Tags: ruby

I am trying to pull up a markdown file from a database that I created. My server. rb file has the following:

```
get "/designers/:id" do
  id = params[:id]
  @content = conn.exec_params("SELECT * FROM articles_info WHERE id = $1",[id]).first
  erb :raf
end
```

In that table is the following markdown information:

```
# **RAF SIMONS**
*THIS IS THE RAF SIMONS BIO* :blush:
*[Raf Link](http://rafsimons.com/)*
```

The .erb file works when I have plain text or the following in it:

```
<%= "#{@content["content"]}" %>
```

However it only prints the actual .md text as it is. So I have tried using Redcarpet to render the markdown file. The code is as follows in my .erb:

```
renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)
<%= markdown.render(@content.content) %>
```

But I am getting the error:

> ArgumentError at /designers/1
>   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)

Which is stemming from the <%= line. I thought at first that the syntax was wrong, so I tried:

```
markdown.render <%= "#{@content["content"]} %>
```

However that did not change anything. I also tried adding in a method in the server.rb file, but that gave me more errors. I read through the entire documentation: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet file but am not understanding where the error is coming from. Is it possible that I need extensions in order to make it work? I also tried:

```
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown::new(renderer, extensions={})
```

But that didn't change anything. Not sure what else to try here! I know that it is tricky but I thought I had a handle on it and have now tried many different iterations and still am having trouble executing it. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace here?

Comment: You won’t get  an `ArgumentError` from the code you’ve given, as the setup of the Markdown object isn’t inside `<% ... %>` so will just be seen as text – you’ll just get ``undefined local variable or method `markdown'``. What’s the full error message?